# Remove (#) from URL in Silverlight

Tags: javascript, c#, html, silverlight

I have a URL e.g. http://localhost:8000/#Test/Method

I am doing following:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.CurrentBookmark = string.Empty;
```

which just remove Test/Method but not '#'

I need to modify browser URL
as: 
http://localhost:8000/

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are manipulating a `String` you can use the following method :

```
String Url = "Foo#Bar";
Url = Url.Replace("#", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expression

```
String url = "http://localhost:8000/#Test/Method"
    url = url.replace(/#/g, "");
```

The above reg expression will scan for all occurrences of '#' character and replaces with empty character

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: 'http://localhost:8000/#test/method' which I need to update as 'http://localhost:8000' after the requested page is loaded. Problem is the if same URL is requested then it is not opened because previous and current URL same. For this reason I need to remove hash bookmark with # symbol

Comment: System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.CurrentBookmark = string.Empty;
will remove Test/Method na??
then System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.CurrentBookmark = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.CurrentBookmark.replace(/#/g, ""); 
will remove the #